# When calling -reloadData, -collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When calling `-reloadData` several times, `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` or `-collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` not called.
(When calling once or twice, the method is called correctly.)
Running `-reloadData` is not taking a lot of time. Memory or CPU usage is also not busy.
Why are there times when `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is not called?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    CustomCollectionCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"select %d", indexPath.item);
    [collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"deselect %d", indexPath.item);
    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

CustomCollectionCell.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {        
        //
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why would `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` be called when you `-reloadData`?

Comment: because of changing cell property and reflect the change to the cell by calling `-reloadData`.

Comment: Yeah but `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is called when the user taps a cell.

Comment: Did you check your collectionView's dataSource and delegate?

Comment: @kusumoto_teruya: Hi.. Did you find a solution to your problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @kusumoto_teruya Any news on this issue? Having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to add ***numberOfItemsInSection*** function to your code. It returns the number of items in the specified section. Without this you can't call ***collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath*** function.

Also call your `[collectionView reloadData];` in your viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.yourArray count];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the method `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` is written.

Comment: Did you check your collectionView's dataSource and delegate?